# Django - Using {% for field in form %} on checkboxes, causes field to generate all alternatives

Tags: django, forms

In my template I would like to display all my checkboxes, but having custom  tags between each alternative. But the {{ field }} tag (to my surprise) does not generate one alternative at a time but rather spits out everything at once, since all alternatives belong to the same "field". How can I iterate through each alternative instead? See code example below.

What I have:

**template.html**

```
<div id="checkRadios">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        {% for field in form %}
            <div class="checkbox">
                {{ field }}
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

**What I get:**

```
<div id="checkRadios">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label for="id_0"><input type="checkbox" name="name_0" value="26" id="id_0" />
        one</label>

        <label for="id_1"><input type="checkbox" name="name_1" value="27" id="id_1" />
        two</label>
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**What I want:**

```
<div id="checkRadios">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label for="id_0"><input type="checkbox" name="name_0" value="26" id="id_0" />
        one</label>
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label for="id_1"><input type="checkbox" name="name_1" value="27" id="id_1" />
        two</label>
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You will need to iterate again on the `{{ field }}` with another for loop I think.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that. But I could not find something like that on the internet.

Comment: I don't think there is any mistake in your code, it will generate what you want, check your divs whether they are ended correctly.